# how to clean datagridview in C# - but stay with the originals columns header

Tags: c#

i have DatagridView in my C# program and i want to clean the grid

(that the grid will be empty)

i try `dataGridView1.DataSource = null;`

but it clean my header columns too

how i can only clean the grid and leave the originals columns ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datgrid.rows.clear();

this will be OK..!!